# How to get only the news part from an HTML?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I`m Pretty new to programming
But I only need the news article, is there an easy way to remove the unnecessary HTML from the text as I have to further iterate over a number of links and then perform sentiment analysis on them.

```
p = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/earnings/cadila-health-consolidated-december-2018-net-sales-at-rs-3577-90-crore-up-9-77-y-o-y-3497711.html'
html = requests.get(p)
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
    date = soup1.find_all("div", {"class":"arttidate"})
    print(date)
    article = soup1.find_all("script", {"class":"arti-flow"})
    print(article)
```

The output is the following

```
[ < div class = "arttidate " > Last Updated: Feb 07, 2019 03: 05 PM IST | Source: < span > Moneycontrol.com < /span></div > ]
[ < div class = "arti-flow"
    id = "article-main" >
    <!-- .CONTENT BODY -->
    <
    p > < div class = "top_dis"
    id = "div_app_container" > < b > Reported Consolidated quarterly numbers
    for Cadila Healthcare are: < /b></div > < /p><p>Net Sales at Rs 3,577.90 crore in December 2018 up 9.77% from Rs. 3,259.60 crore in December 2017.</p > < p > Quarterly Net Profit at Rs.510.70 crore in December 2018 down 6 % from Rs.543.30 crore in December 2017. < /p><div class="ads-320-250 show-moblie mid-arti-ad"><div id="Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News / MC_WAP_News_Internal_300x250_Middle_2 "> <
    script type = "text/javascript" >
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    adKey = "Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_300x250_Middle_2";
    if (width >= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol") != -1 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") < 0) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_300x250_Middle_2")
        });
    }

    if (width <= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") != -1) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_300x250_Middle_2")
        });
    }

    <
    /script> <
    /div></div > < div class = "hide-moblie mid-arti-ad" > < div id = "Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_OutStream" >
    <
    script type = "text/javascript" >
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    adKey = "Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_OutStream";
    if (width >= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol") != -1 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") < 0) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_OutStream")
        });
    }

    if (width <= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") != -1) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP/MC_WAP_News/MC_WAP_News_Internal_OutStream")
        });
    }

    <
    /script> <
    /div></div > < script >
    date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie("dfp_cookie_article", "Y1", {
        expires: date,
        path: "/",
        domain: ".moneycontrol.com"
    }); < /script><p>EBITDA stands at Rs. 870.90 crore in December 2018 down 1.29% from Rs. 882.30 crore in December 2017.</p > < div class = "hide-moblie mid-arti-ad" > < div id = "Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_Article_Native" >
    <
    script type = "text/javascript" >
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    adKey = "Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_Article_Native";
    if (width >= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol") != -1 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") < 0) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_Article_Native")
        });
    }

    if (width <= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") != -1) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_Article_Native")
        });
    }

    <
    /script> <
    /div></div > < div class = "hide-moblie mid-arti-ad" > < div id = "Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_OutStream" >
    <
    script type = "text/javascript" >
    var width = window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    adKey = "Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_OutStream";
    if (width >= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol") != -1 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") < 0) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_OutStream")
        });
    }

    if (width <= 768 && adKey.indexOf("Moneycontrol_Mobile_WAP") != -1) {
        googletag.cmd.push(function() {
            googletag.display("Moneycontrol/MC_News/MC_News_Internal_OutStream")
        });
    }

    <
    /script> <
    /div></div > < script >
    date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    $.cookie("dfp_cookie_article", "Y1", {
        expires: date,
        path: "/",
        domain: ".moneycontrol.com"
    }); < /script><p>Cadila Health EPS has decreased to Rs. 4.99 in December 2018 from Rs. 5.31 in December 2017.</p > < p > Cadila Health shares closed at 317.95 on February 06, 2019(NSE) and has given - 16.39 % returns over the last 6 months and - 21.40 % over the last 12 months. < /p></div >
]
```

The actual desired result would be:-
Net Sales at Rs 3,577.90 crore in December 2018 up 9.77% from Rs. 3,259.60 crore in December 2017.

Quarterly Net Profit at Rs. 510.70 crores in December 2018 down 6% from Rs. 543.30 crore in December 2017. EBITDA stands at Rs. 870.90 crores in December 2018 down 1.29% from Rs. 882.30 crore in December 2017. Cadila Health EPS has decreased to Rs. 4.99 in December 2018 from Rs. 5.31 in December 2017.

Cadila Health shares closed at 317.95 on February 06, 2019 (NSE) and have given -16.39% returns over the last 6 months and -21.40% over the last 12 months.

Edit: While writing this output I realized that all the news that I want is contained in "p" tags, so I would have to grab the news article into another object and read only "p" tags, can someone guide me who can I go doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want the text inside the different `<p>` tag

To do this you can find all the `<p>` tag and apply a `get_text()` on it:

```
p = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/earnings/cadila-health-consolidated-december-2018-net-sales-at-rs-3577-90-crore-up-9-77-y-o-y-3497711.html'

html = requests.get(p)
soup1 = BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')

para = soup1.find_all('p')

result = []
for p in para:
    result.append(p.get_text())

print(result)
```

Output will be:

```
['Reported Consolidated quarterly numbers for Cadila Healthcare are:',
 'Net Sales at Rs 3,577.90 crore in December 2018 up 9.77% from Rs. 3,259.60 '
 'crore in December 2017.',
 'Quarterly Net Profit at Rs. 510.70 crore in December 2018 down 6% from Rs. '
 '543.30 crore in December 2017.',
 'EBITDA stands at Rs. 870.90 crore in December 2018 down 1.29% from Rs. '
 '882.30 crore in December 2017.',
 'Cadila Health EPS has decreased to Rs. 4.99 in December 2018 from Rs. 5.31 '
 'in December 2017.',
 'Cadila Health shares closed at 317.95 on February 06, 2019 (NSE) and has '
 'given -16.39% returns over the last 6 months and -21.40% over the last 12 '
 'months.',
 'Podcast | NSE Invest O Cast episode 5: Harsh Roongta on the benefits of SIP',
 ' Copyright © e-Eighteen.com Ltd. All rights reserved. Reproduction of news '
 'articles, photos, videos or any other content in whole or in part in any '
 'form \r\n'
 '        or medium without express writtern permission of moneycontrol.com is '
 'prohibited.',
 '\n'
 ' Copyright © e-Eighteen.com Ltd All rights resderved. Reproduction of news '
 'articles, photos, videos or any other content in whole or in part in any '
 'form or medium without express writtern permission of moneycontrol.com is '
 'prohibited.\r\n'
 '\t\t']
```

You can finally skip some of them or apply a regex on it

Comment: @AbhishekPal you are welcome, could you please accept the answer and up it? :-)

Comment: Sorry for asking this, but how would you make all the news as one element of the list as opposed to having the parts of the news as elements of the list, thanks. so that the list result can have the news for URLs other than p.

Comment: @Maaz, you can simply just join them. `joined_result = ''.join(ele for ele in result)`

Comment: @chitown88 I couldn't really understand, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @AbhishekPal `join` method will join the different element of result in the same string

Another way but much less pretty is as follows:

    `joined_result = ' '
    for ele in result:
        joined_result = joined_result + ' ' + ele
    print(joined_result)`

Comment: Maaz, sorry about that, I meant to direct the comment to @AbhishekPal. But Maaz's comment is correct. It basically takes each element in your list, and concatenates them. So what the code says is, for each element in the result list, join together with no characters between them. The `''` indicates what to put between each element. If you change that to `' '`, it'll put a white space between each element.

Answer (score 2):

You can also grab that json format within the `<script>` tags.

```
import requests
import bs4
import json

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'}

p = 'https://www.moneycontrol.com/news/business/earnings/cadila-health-consolidated-december-2018-net-sales-at-rs-3577-90-crore-up-9-77-y-o-y-3497711.html'
html = requests.get(p, headers=headers)
soup1 = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html.text,'html.parser')
date = soup1.find_all("div", {"class":"arttidate"})
print(date)
scripts = soup1.find_all("script", {'type':'application/ld+json'})

jsonObj = None

for script in scripts:
    if "articleBody" in script.text:
        jsonStr = script.text.strip()
        jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr, strict=False)

        article = jsonObj[0]['articleBody']

print(article)
```

**Output:**

```
Reported Consolidated quarterly numbers for Cadila Healthcare are:

Net Sales at Rs 3,577.90 crore in December 2018 up 9.77% from Rs. 3,259.60 crore in December 2017.

Quarterly Net Profit at Rs. 510.70 crore in December 2018 down 6% from Rs. 543.30 crore in December 2017.

EBITDA stands at Rs. 870.90 crore in December 2018 down 1.29% from Rs. 882.30 crore in December 2017.

Cadila Health EPS has decreased to Rs. 4.99 in December 2018 from Rs. 5.31 in December 2017.

Cadila Health shares closed at 317.95 on February 06, 2019 (NSE) and has given -16.39% returns over the last 6 months and -21.40% over the last 12 months.









Cadila Healthcare


Consolidated Quarterly Results
in Rs. Cr.











Dec'18
Sep'18
Dec'17


Net Sales/Income from operations
3,516.10
2,844.10
3,191.80


Other Operating Income
61.80
117.10
67.80


Total Income From Operations
3,577.90
2,961.20
3,259.60


EXPENDITURE


Consumption of Raw Materials
590.50
658.30
661.00


Purchase of Traded Goods
620.50
465.10
495.90


Increase/Decrease in Stocks
141.20
-131.50
-32.30


Power &amp;amp;amp; Fuel
--
--
--


Employees Cost
524.00
521.20
460.80


Depreciation
153.70
147.50
147.30


Excise Duty
--
--
--


Admin. And Selling Expenses
--
--
--


R &amp;amp;amp; D Expenses
--
--
--


Provisions And Contingencies
--
--
--


Exp. Capitalised
--
--
--


Other Expenses
861.80
760.30
833.00


P/L Before Other Inc., Int., Excpt. Items &amp;amp;amp; Tax
686.20
540.30
693.90


Other Income
31.00
30.40
41.10


P/L Before Int., Excpt. Items &amp;amp;amp; Tax
717.20
570.70
735.00


Interest
45.50
35.70
13.50


P/L Before Exceptional Items &amp;amp;amp; Tax
671.70
535.00
721.50


Exceptional Items
--
--
--


P/L Before Tax
671.70
535.00
721.50


Tax
158.60
124.70
178.60


P/L After Tax from Ordinary Activities
513.10
410.30
542.90


Prior Year Adjustments
--
--
--


Extra Ordinary Items
--
--
--


Net Profit/(Loss) For the Period
513.10
410.30
542.90


Minority Interest
-10.90
-10.70
-10.10


Share Of P/L Of Associates
8.50
17.90
10.50


Net P/L After M.I &amp;amp;amp; Associates
510.70
417.50
543.30


Equity Share Capital
102.40
102.40
102.40


Reserves Excluding Revaluation Reserves
--
--
--


Equity Dividend Rate (%)
--
--
--


EPS Before Extra Ordinary


Basic EPS
4.99
4.08
5.31


Diluted EPS
4.99
4.08
5.31


EPS After Extra Ordinary


Basic EPS
4.99
4.08
5.31


Diluted EPS
4.99
4.08
5.31


Public Share Holding


No Of Shares (Crores)
--
--
--


Share Holding (%)
--
--
--


Promoters and Promoter Group Shareholding


a) Pledged/Encumbered


- Number of shares (Crores)
--
--
--


- Per. of shares (as a % of the total sh. of prom. and promoter group)
--
--
--


- Per. of shares (as a % of the total Share Cap. of the company)
--
--
--


b) Non-encumbered


- Number of shares (Crores)
--
--
--


- Per. of shares (as a % of the total sh. of prom. and promoter group)
--
--
--


- Per. of shares (as a % of the total Share Cap. of the company)
--
--
--


Source :  Dion Global Solutions Limited
```

Comment: Thanks, but I`m not well versed with json, even beautifulsoup is too much for me. appreciate the help though

Comment: No worries. But just something to keep in mind in the future while you are still learning beautifulsoup and html. I was the same, I had no clue what json structures are/meant. Once I learned it though, I saw the benefits of it. Sometimes you'll see the data only stored within the json, and other times, you can get a json response from `requests.get`. Just makes it easier if it's already in a nice structured way. But it all comes in time. Keep working at BeautifulSoup as the more practice, the better you'll get and you'll learn new things all the time...and it's fun! Good luck!